# How to call a phone number using gsm & python

Tags: python

How to call a phone number using gsm & python. i have try many software in window, but i can't found it using python.

Answer (score 0):

You should open a COM serial port to the gsm modem from python and use AT commands, search Wikipedia for those, they are used to communicate with gsm devices

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111277/Cellular-Development-with-Telit-GSM-Module-and-Pyt), perhaps it works for you.

Personally iv'e used successfully the GSMComm library for the .NET framework. If it's possible, perhaps you should consider using this library via IronPython.